# Bad state: There were unclaimed errors, when create subscription in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I getting this error when create a subscription in Google Play Console.

Bad state: There were unclaimed errors, {global/VALIDATE_IN_APP_MESSAGE_INVALID_CURRENCY_FOR_DEFAULT_PRICE}

I try in old app and new app, but still no luck.
I have to test my subscription before release.

I send it to support but waiting for 3 days but not receive respond yet
any one have faced this problem ? Or could you please try in your account. 
Thank you.

[Google Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JAve.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the console. I found an express method how to fix it.

First you need to create a price template.
Here you can find how to do it.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?p=pricing_template

And then you can use this template on the subscription page.
Good luck.

Comment: You save my day. A have added my subscription.
Thank you